# Is $X$ diffeomorphic to its diagonal?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds

I missed geometry in school, I'm trying to fill in the gaps by reading Pollack's Differential Topology. Am I doing this right?

This is #16 in the first section. Show the diagonal $\Delta$ of $X\times X$ is diffeomorphic to $X$.

All sets are subsets of some Euclidean space. I define $\phi:X\to X\times X$ by $\phi(x)=(x,x)$. Clearly $\phi$ is a bijection of $X$ and $\Delta$. If $x\in X$, let $U_x$ be an open nbhd of $x$ in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^k$. Define $F:U_x\to\mathbb{R}^{2k}$ by $F(x)=(x,x)$. I suspect $F$ is smooth. Notice if $y\in U_x$, 
$$
\begin{align*}
dF_y(z)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(y+hz)-F(y)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(y+hz,y+hz)-(y,y)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} (z,z)=F(z)
\end{align*}
$$
so $dF_y=F$. This implies $F$ is smooth. Since $F=\phi$ on $U_x\cap X$, $\phi$ is also smooth. Finally, $\phi^{-1}\colon\Delta\to X$ is just a projection map on the first coordinate, and I know projections are smooth. So $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism of $X$ and $\Delta$.

Is this sensible? Sorry, I don't have any place to get feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Seems fine to me. It's always nice to remember that a map to a product of manifolds is smooth if and only if its coordinate functions are. :)

Comment: Thx Alex Youcis for the feedback :)